# Class for overloaded method accepts template and base class - How to default a certain method?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, inheritance

I am using the curiously-recurrent template pattern for a problem in C++. 
In certain instances using the same method I need to return a sub class or a base class.

Therefor the method dec would be something like

```
base& get() {
 return base_ref || deriv_ref; //depends on impl
}
```

while I have other methods such as

```
template <typename deriv> 
class base {

 void run(deriv& d) {//deriv specific method/derived class/}
 void run(base& b)  { //base specific method// }
}
```

However whenever I return a `derived class` (that is reinterperted as a `base&`) the methods default to the `base` class implementation as shown below.

```
template<typename d>
struct base {

    void run(d& type) {
        std::cout << "deriv " << std::endl;
    }
    void run(base& type) {
        std::cout << "base" << std::endl;
    }
    base& alter(d& der) {
        return der;
    }
    d& no_alt(d& der) {
        return der;
    }
};
struct deriv : public base<deriv> {

};
int main() {
    deriv foo;
    base<deriv> bar;
    bar.run(foo);           //prints deriv
    bar.run(bar);           //print base
    bar.run(bar.alter(foo));//print base (Need this to print deriv)
    bar.run(bar.no_alt(foo));//print deriv

}
```

How can I have the method default to the `derived_methods` in these instances?

Additionally I would think the compiler should give a poorly-defined warning (as it basically has two methods that accept the same type).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but from what I can see, there is no error with the output

Comment: Hey I meant for the above methods to be by reference not by value, question should make sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alter` returns type `base&`. This means that the statement `bar.run(bar.alter(foo));` will evaluate `bar.alter(foo)`, which returns a reference to `foo` cast as a `base&`. Then, `bar.run()` is called with that `base&` reference.

You are not receiving a warning, because you gave the function a `base&` and only one overload takes `base&`. If you want this particular code to call the `deriv&` overload of `run`, you will need to change the `base&` overload to something like this:

```
void run(base& type) {
    deriv* derivTest = dynamic_cast<deriv*>(&type);
    if( derivTest != nullptr )
        run(*derivTest);
    else
        std::cout << "base" << std::endl;
}
```

This checks if the reference passed in is really a reference to `deriv`, and calls the correct `run` when needed. Notice that going through a pointer type prevents an exception in the event that the `dynamic_cast` fails.

Comment: Hey sorry, I meant for those methods to be by reference not value, question should make sense now.

Comment: I will update my answer, but the compiler will still see a function outputting a `base&` type and choose the `base&` overload of the function. If you want to have `run` act differently for `deriv&` objects in this case, then you will need to perform a `dynamic_cast` and see if it fails.